# NegativeArraySizeException -1

Tags: java, android, rest

I am developing an Android application that is making a call to a RESTful server through HTTP. Problem is, I am getting the following error: **`NegativeArraySizeException -1`**. I can't figure out why the problem is happening.

I have two classes: `ReadHttpTask` and `HttpHelper`. The error seems to be caused by the StringBuilder inside the HttpHelper class or that is at least where the debugger shows the cause of the exception.

**ReadHttpTask:**

```
public class ReadHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, CharSequence> {
    @Override
    protected CharSequence doInBackground(String...urls) {
        String urlString = urls[0];
        try{
            CharSequence result = HttpHelper.GetHttpResponse(urlString);
            return result;
        } catch (IOException ex){
            cancel(true);
            String errorMessage = ex.getMessage() + "\n" + urlString;
            Log.e("Something went wrong", errorMessage);
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

**HttpHelper:**

```
public class HttpHelper {

    public static CharSequence GetHttpResponse(String urlString) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        if(!(connection instanceof HttpURLConnection)){
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        }

        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            String responseMessage = httpConnection.getResponseMessage();
            throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + responseCode + " " + responseMessage);

        }
        InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(httpConnection.getContentLength());
            while(true){
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if(line==null) break;
                result.append(line);
            }
            return result;
        } finally {
            if(reader != null) reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll only get a `NegativeArraySizeException` if you're trying to create an array - and I can't see where you're doing that in this code. Please include a full stack trace, and indicate the relevant line numbers in the code above.

Comment: Read this : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength() Like you said, this come from the Stringbuilder receive -1. Why, well check the method you use to create this instance. The doc tell you that it could return -1 in two cases.

Comment: @AndyTurner, StringBuilder use this exception too since it is a dynamic char array ;)

Comment: where is the stacktrace?

Comment: Also: `result.append(line).append("\n");` as line does not contain the line separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `getContentLength`methods from `URLConnection` the create an instance of StringBuilder.

First, let see the StringBuilder :

> StringBuilder public StringBuilder(int capacity)
>
> Constructs a string builder with no characters in it and an initial
>   capacity specified by the capacity argument. Parameters:capacity - the
>   initial capacity.
>   **Throws:NegativeArraySizeException - if the capacity
>   argument is less than 0.**

If you open the doc, you will see :

> Returns
>
> int the content length of the resource that this connection's URL
>   references, **-1 if the content length is not known, or if the content
>   length is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE.**

So you have your solution. You should not create the StringBuilder with a specific size if this is -1, if you receive a value you can. If not, let the SB manage is own size.

Create the StringBuilder like this :

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(); //create with a size of 16 character.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a bit confused about how to let the SB manage its own size. If I am understanding you correctly then the `httpConnection.getContentLength();` is the one that specifies the size of the SB but how else would you get the content length if not like that?

Comment: @kennyYice23 Well, you should know that a stringBuilder is an array of character that manager itself is size, so if you append the instance and the array is to small, it will resize it. So basicly, just create a StringBuilder without parameter. It will create an array of 15 I think, when more character will arrived, the array will grow, no out of bound exception will append (can't say what is the memory limit of the array...). 
 
 
I have added the line to create the SB

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar exception. This was thrown when table/view/procedure was not present in DB.I was injecting the package name and procedure name from constructor injection and trying to compile the simplejdbccall, as the procedure was not present it threw the same error.